# cmake disable optimization with /Od

Tags: cmake

The CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is **Release**, 
I tried this to disable the optimization:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Od ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

but it doesn't work, it displays:

`cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Od' with '/O2'`

How to set the optimization level in cmake? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to modify `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`, for example:

```
STRING(REPLACE "-O2" "-Od" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
```

Comment: That's it, on my VC compiler it's `STRING(REPLACE "/O2" "/Od" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
`,  thanks.